# InfluxDB sum last points

Tags: flux-influxdb

I have a measurement of the player counts on multiple game servers, every time a player leaves or joins the server, the server writes a point to influx containing the player count and the server's unique id.

What I am trying to do is sum the last point for each unique server id.

example points:

```
04:30 server-a: 45
04:31 server-b: 56
04:32 server-a: 78
```

the current total would be: 134

I have been able to get the last points for each server with the following query.

```
from(bucket: "metrics")
  |> range(start: -1m)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "player_count")
  |> last()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group your data and then sum it.
Add this to your influx query:

```
|> group()
|> sum()
```

Comment: Ah, I was playing with the group function but I never tried to just leave it empty!
Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what I needed thanks. Also added `|> last()` prior to apply the operation on only the last set of points.